# unification in prolog failure

Tags: prolog, unification

Can anyone please tell me why this fails?

```
f(X,X) = f(a,b).
```

It was my assumption that X would first be instantiated to a, then removed, then to b making just X = b. Trying it out, I see that I am wrong but I do not know why.

Thank you.

Comment: Since `a` and `b` are distinct atoms, `X` can't be both at the same time. You could say, `f(X,Y) = f(a,b)` and get `X = a` and `Y = b`. Why would you assume that `X` would instantiate to `a` and then be "removed"? What does "removed" mean in this context?

Comment: Thank you; this makes sense now. When I said 'removed' I was thinking of backtracking, which is another concept I have only a loose grasp on.

Comment: It's a single expression, so there's nothing to backtrack to. Prolog doesn't break it into finer pieces. In this case, even if it did, backtracking would fail because, again, the expression is asking for `X` to be `a` and to be `b` simultaneously. If I said, `X = a, X = b.` that will always fail since Prolog will backtrack from `X = b` on it not matching, but `X = a` will have no more choices to make to attempt success (it offers only one: `X = a`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unification always gives variables a consistent meaning.  There is no value of X that makes `f(X,X) = f(a,b)` true.  If you said

```
f(X) = f(a); f(X) = f(b).
```

Then you would get a result more like you are expecting.